# Python gets KeyError on "del FilmName[NewCinema]"

Tags: python

I am making a simple code, using what I know about Python, then suddenly, I get an error, saying I misplaced an 'r', in a line, which doesn't even have an 'r' in it, I am totally stumped, I am very new to Python, so I don't know where to start debugging or to search online, so I came to Stack Overflow, hoping for an answer and some advice on debugging problems like this one, thanks

Steps to reproduce:  type "Remove", then "Bourne"

btw I also did not know which code I should include...

```
NewSpace = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
Sold = 0

Cinema = {
    1:125,
    2:150,
    3:200,
    4:100
    }

Film = {
    "Finding Dory" : {"AgeR":3,"Seats":125,"Cinema": 1},
    "Bourne" : {"AgeR":18,"Seats":150,"Cinema": 2},
    "Tarzan" : {"AgeR":13,"Seats":175,"Cinema": 3}, 
    "Ghost Busters" : {"AgeR":13,"Seats":100,"Cinema": 4} 
    }

FilmName = {
    1 : {"Name":"Finding Dory"},
    2 : {"Name":"Bourne"},
    3 : {"Name":"Tarzan"}, 
    4 : {"Name":"Ghost Busters"} 
    }


def Remove():
    X = 1
    while X == 1:     
        Remove = input("What film should be removed? ")
        if Remove in Film:
        X = 0
    else:
        print("Name not recognized, retry:")
return Remove

def Available():
    Which = input("Which Movie do you want to check? ")
    X = 1

    while X == 1: 
    
        if Which in Film:
            print (Film[Which]["Seats"])
            Cont = input("Continue or Exit?(c/e) ").strip().lower()
            X = 0
        
            if Cont == "c":
                continue
                print("\n\n")
            else:
                break
        
        else:
            print("Name not recognized, retry")


def AllMovies():
    Num = len(FilmName)
    X = 1    
    print("Available movies: ")

    while X <= Num:
    
        print(FilmName[X]["Name"])
        X = X+1

if len(Cinema) == 0:
    X = 1
    Cin = int(input("Insert total amount of cinemas: ").strip())
      
    while X <= Cin:
        Seats = int(input("Seats in Cinema {}: ".format(X)).strip())
        Cinema[X] = Seats
        X = X + 1
        
    X = 1
    
    while X <= Cin:
        Mov1 = str(input("Name of Movie {}: ".format(X)).strip())
        Age1 = int(input("Age rating: ").strip())
        Cinema1 = int(input("Which cinema: ").strip())
        Film[Mov1] = {"AgeR":Age1,"Seats": Cinema[Cinema1], "Cinema": Cinema1}
        FilmName[Cinema1] = {"Name" : Mov1}
        print(NewSpace)
        X = X + 1


while True:
    AllMovies()
    Movie = input("What Movie would you like to see? ").strip().title()

    if Movie in Film:
        Age = int(input("How old are you? ").strip())
    
        if Age >= Film[Movie]["AgeR"]:
            if Film[Movie]["Seats"] > 0:
                Film[Movie]["Seats"] = Film[Movie]["Seats"]-1
                Sold = Sold + 1
                print("Enjoy your movie: {}, at cinema {}".format(Movie, Film[Movie]["Cinema"]))
                break
        else:
            print(NewSpace)
            print("You are too young, choose another film")
            print("\n\n")
        
    elif Movie == "E":
        break

    elif Movie == "Remove":
         Remove = Remove()
         NewCinema = Remove[3]
         print(Remove[3])
         del Film[Remove]
         del FilmName[NewCinema]
         Mov1 = str(input("Name of new movie: ").strip())
         Age1 = int(input("Age rating: ").strip())
         Film[Mov1] = {"AgeR":Age1,"Seats": Cinema[NewCinema], "Cinema": Cinema1}
         FilmName[NewCinema] = {"Name" : Mov1}
            
    elif Movie == "Available":
        Available()
    
    elif Movie == "Sales":
        print("You have sold {} tickets".format(Sold))
        print("\n\n\n")

    else:
        print(NewSpace)
        print("We don't have that film... Pick another one")
        print("\n\n")
```

runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonBible/cinima.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonBible')

Available movies:
Finding Dory
Bourne
Tarzan
Ghost Busters

What Movie would you like to see? Remove

What film should be removed? Bourne

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-5a7fa0b19f3b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonBible/cinima.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonBible')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonBible/cinima.py", line 123, in <module>
    del FilmName[NewCinema]

KeyError: 'r'
```

Comment: When you say "solved", it's better to accept the answer which is helpful to you, or post another answer saying how you solved that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is descriptive. You are calling `del FilmName[NewCinema]` and `NewCinema` is only `'r'` - and your dictionary does not have a film under a key of `'r'` - hence: `KeyError`.

Use `print()` statements to print before/around the location where the error happen and inspect your variables. Even better: learn how to debug: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

For now you should change the line

```
elif Movie == "Remove":
     Remove = Remove()
     NewCinema = Remove   # [3]  is wrong - you set NewCinima to one character
     print(Remove[3])
     del Film[Remove]
     del FilmName[NewCinema]
```

You now need to figure out how the key into your FilmName Dictionary is called - because you use integers there.

You probably should overthink the whole "data-storage" design - you already got the `FilmName` as `key` into your `Film`-dictionary , so no need to store the name inside another `dict` under an `integer` key that holds yet another `dict` that has a `name` key that contains the films name...

Comment: I just saw it, I almost face planted a hole through my head, I tested, what happens when I use different "Films" and saw the 4 letter was always selected, then read through my script, and saw the [3], I think I just got confused(/ tired, it is 2 in the morning here), I was actually suppose to say      `NewCinema = Film[Remove]["Cinema"]`      but thanks for the method, I hope using that and thinking more logical, I wont make stupid mistakes again, thanks